# find the machine manufacturer name using NodeJS, for eg, HP, Dell, Lenovo, etc

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to find the machine manufacturer name using NodeJS, for eg, HP, Dell, Lenovo, etc
I require it for a report being generated and it is for one of the fields

Comment: what operating system? windows 10 you could execute `wmic baseboard get  manufacturer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library that does what you want, check it out here: https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation

Here is a small example what you would need to do with it to get your result:

```js
const si = require('systeminformation');

const systemInfo = await si.system();

console.log(systemInfo.manufacturer);
```